# Best way to sort an NSArray of custom objects by an alphanumerical property

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor

As I say in the title, I have an `NSArray` of objects which in turn have an `NSString` property with this format (I provide a kind of regex to explain): [1-9]+[A-Z]*

I'd like to sort such array firstly by the first numerical characters, and then by the last alphabetical characters, for example: if I have 6 objects with the strings [@"1", @"1A", @"3", @"2D", @"10B", @"1B"], I'd want to get the sorted array [@"1", @"1A", @"1B", @"2D", @"3", @"10B"].

Since I want to sort by a property that is an `NSString`, how could I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe if you would check ASCII values of characters?

Comment: What about NSNumericSearch for compare: `[array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2){return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];}];`

Comment: @Larme thanks, but that doesn't seem to take into account the alphabetical substring...

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy approach available to do the same stuff:

```
NSArray *unsortedArray =  @[@"1", @"1A", @"3", @"2D", @"10B", @"1B"];
NSArray *sortedArray  = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];

NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
```

Enjoy ur coding....:)

Comment: I actually don't have an array of strings, but an array of `NSObject` I want to sort by an `NSString` property... on the other hand, if I simply sort the strings, I get @"10B" before @"2D"

Comment: By this approach u'll get @"10B" after @"2D",Here is the log: (
    1,
    1A,
    1B,
    2D,
    3,
    10B
)